# Extending the Homotopy formula of Federer 4.1.9 to Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Is it possible to extend the Homotopy Formula expressed for classical currents in open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to currents in a Riemannian manifold? (see Federer's book Geometric Measure Theory 4.1.9)

I believe that this should be the case by just translating everything in the Riemannian setting but I would appreciate very much if you could confirm this.